# Securing Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript file within my website how can I store the code in a separate file on the same server but it still activates with the password function the code is

```
<script>
  function passWord() {
    var testV = 1;
    var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your School Code',' ');
    while (testV < 3) {
      if (!pass1)
      history.go(-1);
        if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "0000") {
          window.open('Discussion.html','_self')
          break;
        }
      testV+=1;
      var pass1 =
      prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.','Password');
  }

  if (pass1.toLowerCase()!="password" & testV ==3)
    history.go(-1);
    return " ";
  }
```

It runs with

```
<input type="button" value="Enter page" onClick="passWord()">
```

Comment: `I have a javascript script within my website to secure a page` No you don't. You just can't secure a website purely on the client side. It would be trivial to see what the password is by just looking at the page source. Putting it in a separate file would do absolutely nothing to make it more secure. Do security properly.

Comment: Question is too broad and should be narrowed down to a specific issue that can be answered in a narrower scope. As is the proper answer to this question would resemble a book on web security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter how you store the password, it will always be accessible to the client if you send it to the client.

That is, you cannot have a secure password verification that is done in JavaScript, short of using a one-way hash function.  Even if you did use a one-way hash function, someone could just bypass your JavaScript password verification.  Do password verification server-side.

Comment: This. One million times. Never, ever implement the full authentication flow on the client side.

Comment: @trnelson Ok I agree, but how can I source a .js file to run when the password function is clicked.

Comment: @SeanCorrigan I don't understand what you mean.  `<script src="something.js"></script>`  If you want to load a JavaScript file dynamically, there are many methods built into frameworks and libraries.  Are you using any?  jQuery has `getScript()`.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: No @brad I want it to run when the user clicks    <input type="button" value="Enter Page" onClick="passWord()">    But i want it to run on a different .js document.

Comment: @SeanCorrigan: You should read up on the [script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) tag. This is basic stuff.